# three time join query in same table

Tags: mysql

i have a one mysql table as

```
  MENU_ID       MENU_NAME    PARENT_ONE     PARENT_TWO
  1             home         0              0
  2             home_sub     1              0
  3             third_home   1              2
```

i want the name against parent one and parent twos id's with each row if have.
 i have tried something but its giving only one that has parent one and two both values like

```
MENU_ID  MENU_NAME  PARENT_ONE   PARENT_TWO     MENU_NAME   MENU_NAME
 3        third_home    1            2              home        home_sub
```

but i want

```
MENU_ID     MENU_NAME   PARENT_ONE  PARENT_TWO  MENU_NAME       MENU_NAME
 1          home            0       0
 2          home_sub        1       0           home
 3          third_home      1       2           home            home_sub



this the query that i tried

SELECT a.*, b.MENU_NAME, c.MENU_NAME 
FROM menu_table a JOIN menu_table b ON a.PARENT_ONE = b.MENU_ID 
JOIN menu_table c ON a.PARENT_TWO = c.MENU_ID ORDER BY a.MENU_ID;
```

advanced thank's if anyone can help me for this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use left join (join is alias for inner join)

```
SELECT a.*, b.MENU_NAME, c.MENU_NAME 
FROM menu_table a 
LEFT JOIN menu_table b ON a.PARENT_ONE = b.MENU_ID 
LEFT JOIN menu_table c ON a.PARENT_TWO = c.MENU_ID 
ORDER BY a.MENU_ID;
```